# How make dynamically *ngxPermissionsOnly in angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I have created a menu dynamically and need to display according to permission but *ngxPermissionsOnly not working. Please suggest what I am doing wrong.

```js
this.sidebarnavItems = [{
        path: '', title: 'User Managment', icon: 'icon-Double-Circle', class: 'has-arrow', label: '', labelClass: '', extralink: false, permission:'',
        submenu: [
            { path: '/user/vuser', title: 'User', icon: '', class: '', label: '', labelClass: '', extralink: false, submenu: [] ,permission:''},
            { path: '/user/vstudent', title: 'Student', icon: '', class: '', label: '', labelClass: '', extralink: false, submenu: [] ,permission:"'5','6','7','8'"},
            { path: '/user/vfaculty', title: 'Faculty', icon: '', class: '', label: '', labelClass: '', extralink: false, submenu: [] ,permission:''},

        ]
    }]
```

```html
<html>


<ul class="collapse" *ngIf="sidebarnavItem.submenu.length > 0" [ngClass]="{'in' : showMenu === sidebarnavItem.title }">
                    <li *ngFor="let sidebarnavSubItem of sidebarnavItem.submenu" [class.active]="showSubMenu === sidebarnavSubItem.title" [routerLinkActive]="sidebarnavSubItem.submenu.length > 0 ? '' : 'active'" >
                      <span *ngxPermissionsOnly = "[sidebarnavSubItem.permission]">
                        <a  [routerLink]="sidebarnavSubItem.submenu.length > 0 ? null : [sidebarnavSubItem.path]" [routerLinkActive]="sidebarnavSubItem.submenu.length > 0 ? '' : 'router-link-active'" [ngClass]="[sidebarnavSubItem.class]" *ngIf="!sidebarnavSubItem.extralink;" (click)="addActiveClass(sidebarnavSubItem.title)" >
                            <i [ngClass]="[sidebarnavSubItem.icon]" ></i>
                                {{sidebarnavSubItem.title}}
                        </a>
                        </span>


                    </li>
                </ul>



</html>
```

Comment: Did you include the permissionsModule to your app/core module?

Comment: From the documentation, I see that they have `only` and `except` .. are you sure you dont need them?

Comment: yes I have included permissionsModule If I  pass permission static then working fine

Comment: Did you try defining the permission in the routes as an array and then accessing just the `sidebarnavSubItem.permission` in the template?

Comment: @callback I have already defined in the routes as an array. If I put  value static like <span *ngxPermissionsOnly = "['5','6','7','8']">...</span> then It is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's problem in format of your permission input & how you binding it to `ngxPermissionsOnly` directive. Update your `sidebarnavItems` to:

```
this.sidebarnavItems = [{
    path: '', title: 'User Managment', icon: 'icon-Double-Circle', class: 'has-arrow', label: '', labelClass: '', extralink: false, permission:'',
    submenu: [
        { path: '/user/vuser', title: 'User', icon: '', class: '', label: '', labelClass: '', extralink: false, submenu: [] ,permission:[]},
        { path: '/user/vstudent', title: 'Student', icon: '', class: '', label: '', labelClass: '', extralink: false, submenu: [] ,permission:['5','6','7','8']},
        { path: '/user/vfaculty', title: 'Faculty', icon: '', class: '', label: '', labelClass: '', extralink: false, submenu: [] ,permission:[]},

    ]
}];
```

Then update your view code as:

```
<ul class="collapse" *ngIf="sidebarnavItem.submenu.length > 0" [ngClass]="{'in' : showMenu === sidebarnavItem.title }">
    <li *ngFor="let sidebarnavSubItem of sidebarnavItem.submenu" [class.active]="showSubMenu === sidebarnavSubItem.title" [routerLinkActive]="sidebarnavSubItem.submenu.length > 0 ? '' : 'active'" >
    <span *ngxPermissionsOnly = "sidebarnavSubItem.permission">
        <a  [routerLink]="sidebarnavSubItem.submenu.length > 0 ? null : [sidebarnavSubItem.path]" [routerLinkActive]="sidebarnavSubItem.submenu.length > 0 ? '' : 'router-link-active'"
            [ngClass]="[sidebarnavSubItem.class]" *ngIf="!sidebarnavSubItem.extralink;" (click)="addActiveClass(sidebarnavSubItem.title)" >
            <i [ngClass]="[sidebarnavSubItem.icon]" ></i>
                {{sidebarnavSubItem.title}}
        </a>
    </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So, here I've just updated `*ngxPermissionsOnly = "sidebarnavSubItem.permission"` where permission property is now array in sidebarnavItems object.

[**Plunker Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/TPwxtXx4F60E4xbdQRCO?p=preview)  to verify. Here check in roles.component.ts

Comment: @PankajKumar this is exactly what I meant in the comment above.. :)